# Displaying A Symbol After Set Time [Action Script]

Tags: flash, actionscript

I was curious if this was possible to display a symbol after a set amount of time? The only method I am aware of in Flash is setting it in the timeline. However I need the animation to loop and if it is set in the timeline it will just hide the symbol again until the animation wraps around where it shows again.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myInterval:uint = setInterval(displaySymbol, 20000);

function displaySymbol():void{
 your_simbol.visible = true;
 clearInterval(myInterval);
}
```

The code above will display the symbol instaced as "your_simbol" after 20 seconds(1000 = 1 second, because its miliseconds)... remember to click in your symbol and on properties dismark option "visible", so, it's going to start without visibility and then get visible.

Not sure if it is exaclty you need... and not sure if you using Actionscript 3.0... i don't know how to do on as2..

However, you have another simple solution... just create a movieclip and start with nothing and at X frame you just display your simbol manually, so, when it's displayed, add a "stop();" in the last frame to keep it displayed...

Try to use movieclips and you will see how better is this, because you're going to need to use it soon probably... It's good because use a different timeline.

Answer (score 0):

The way André suggested works, but you can keep it more simple if you use the setTimeout() function which is ment to be used for delayed events that you only want to handle once. setInterval is used for repeated events.

Docs: http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setTimeout()

Example:

```
function displaySymbol():void{
   yourSymbol.visible=true;
}

setTimeout(displaySymbol, 20000);
```

Another way to handle this is using the Timer class:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html

The link has examples for it.